# Error while requesting server, received a non successful HTTP code [302] with response Body: Create EnvelopeWithHTTPIntfo

Tags: php, docusignapi

Facing the error 302 with no body when trying to create an evelope with docusign php sdk

```php
"trace": [
{
    "file": "/var/www/html/vendor/docusign/esign-client/src/Api/EnvelopesApi.php",
    "line": 4046,
    "function": "callApi",
    "class": "DocuSign\\eSign\\Client\\ApiClient",
    "type": "->"
},
{
    "file": "/var/www/html/vendor/docusign/esign-client/src/Api/EnvelopesApi.php",
    "line": 3966,
    "function": "createEnvelopeWithHttpInfo",
    "class": "DocuSign\\eSign\\Api\\EnvelopesApi",
    "type": "->"
},
```

Comment: Please update (edit) your question to provide more detail. Best would be to include a [DocuSign API log](https://support.docusign.com/en/guides/ndse-user-guide-api-request-logging) so we can see what your API call was to DocuSign.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question needs a lot more details, but one issue to check when you receive a redirect (302) response is that you are using the right URL for the API request.

If you're using the developer (demo) system for the eSignature REST API, then the url should be [https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2.1/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes](https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2.1/accounts/%7BaccountId%7D/envelopes) if you're trying to create an envelope

Comment: correct this was the answer demo.docusign.net/restapi......i was using the account-d subdomain

Comment: Great! Glad to help! Please check/accept the answer. Many thanks, Larry

Answer (score 0):

302 is not an error.

It's a 'Moved Temporarily' message, and the message also includes a `Location:` header that indicates where you should go. There won't normally be a body.

E.g.

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Location: http://www.iana.org/domains/example/
```

You've posted no code, so there's no way to show how to implement this.

[Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/302)